# HTTP authentication - the HTTP header name is Authorization - why?

Tags: authentication, http, authorization, header

Why by HTTP authentication the HTTP header which contains credentials is called "Authorization"? Any historical explanation?

I am asking because I realized that some people mix authentication with authorization and this name convention by HTTP authentication is bit unfortunate.

Comment: Now you understand why people mix them. The name is used in RFC 2068 from Jan 1997 and is clearly used only as a synonym of the credentials in the second meaning from [the dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/authorization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a deeper meaning behind. The usage is consistent with the English language. The Oxford English Learners Dictionary defines [authorization](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/authorization) as:

> 2. [countable] a document that gives somebody official permission to do something.
>
>    *Can I see your authorization?*

The HTTP specification for headers dates back at least to RFC 2068 from January 1997 which clearly states:

> Authorization = Credentials

On the other hand, first security standards that laid ground to ISO 27k series were codified in 1999-2000.